# Skmap custom annotation first load doubled in size

Tags: java, android, skmaps

I'm using 32x32 and 64x64 (retina) for the same icon. When I tried using SKAnnotationView to display my icon, it loads up in double size (128x128). After I clear annotations and add again, the size returns to normal (64x64).

Please find the code below, I followed the sample project code:

```
SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation();
annotation.setUniqueID(-1);

annotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(longitude.doubleValue(), latitude.doubleValue()));

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

SKAnnotationView annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
if (metrics.densityDpi < DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
    annotationView.setDrawableResourceId(R.drawable.ic_annotation);
    annotation.setOffset(new SKScreenPoint(16, 16));
    annotationView.setWidth(32);
    annotationView.setHeight(32);
    annotation.setImageSize(32);
} else {
    annotationView.setDrawableResourceId(R.drawable.ic_annotation_retina);
    annotation.setOffset(new SKScreenPoint(32, 32));
    annotationView.setWidth(64);
    annotationView.setHeight(64);
    annotation.setImageSize(64);
}
annotation.setAnnotationView(annotationView);

mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
```

Comment: I can workaround by deleting the annotation and add again:  `mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);
 new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   mapView.deleteAnnotation(-1);
   mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);

  }
 }, 500);`

Comment: We're looking into this issue (disclosure: I'm working at skobbler)

Comment: Can you Nicholas add a demo project illustrating this issue?

Comment: i think it might happen due to i added the annotation before the mapview finish loading surface or not initialized completely. so you will see the map is being loaded, but then I added an annotation.

Comment: The issue can be investigated only if we have the entire code. If it's possible, please add your demo project. Another idea, try to add "SKAnnotationView" after calling "onSurfaceCreated"

Answer (score 1):

It might be too late , but you can try adding annotation at

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated() {
}
callback.
```

This is my code :

```
public class OfflineMapFragment extends BaseFragment implements SKMapSurfaceListener {

    private void addFilteredAnnotations(){
        SKAnnotation annotation = new SKAnnotation();
        annotation.setUniqueID(15);
        annotation.setLocation(new SKCoordinate(Double.parseDouble(lat,long);
        annotation.setMininumZoomLevel(5);
        annotation.setOffset(new SKScreenPoint(128, 128));
        SKAnnotationView annotationView = new SKAnnotationView();
        annotationView.setDrawableResourceId(R.drawable.map_icon);
        annotationView.setWidth(128);
        annotationView.setHeight(128);
        annotation.setAnnotationView(annotationView);
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation, SKAnimationSettings.ANIMATION_NONE);                
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated() {
        addAnnotation();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I'm not working on that project anymore. Hope other people find it useful!